# Getting error while adding host=-only server in virtual box. [ E_INVALIDARG (0x80070057) ]

Tags: virtualbox, puppet, dhcp

I need to create a new Host-only network, in VirtualBox, as a part of this [tutorial](https://youtu.be/51f5uEPoZns?t=479) to learn Puppet tool. I went to `File -> Preferences -> Network -> Host-only network`, and clicked on "Add host-only network". On clicking ok, **it generated default values of DHCP as 0, in the end (screesnshots below).** Which gave the following **error**:

```
Failed to save the settings.

Invalid server address.

Result Code: E_INVALIDARG (0x80070057)
Component: VirtualBoxWrap
Interface: IVirtualBox {0169423f-46b4-cde9-91af-1e9d5b6cd945}
Callee: IDHCPServer {00c8f974-92c5-44a1-8f3f-702469fdd04b}
```

- [adapter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3dX5I.png)
- [dhcp server (the address values are generated by default)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pqc9m.png)
- [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bGzs1.png)

How should I configure DHCP? so my host-only network is created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uninstalling current VirtualBox and reinstalling with new version (5.2) resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your DHCP server address values do not appear to be the defaults. Are you sure you didn't change something?

The values I see in there by default match those in the Youtube video and they are:

[image]

In your screenshot, you have

- Server Address: 192.168.115.0
- Server Mask: 255.255.255.0
- Lower Address Bound: 192.168.115.0
- Upper Address Bound: 192.168.115.0

That lower/upper address bound are outside of the network specified in Address/Subnet so it is invalid. See [here](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#vboxmanage-dhcpserver) in the VirtualBox docs for the meaning of lower and upper address bound.

Try using `ipcalc` to calculate valid settings:

```
$ ipcalc 192.168.115.0/255.255.255.0
Address:   192.168.115.0        11000000.10101000.01110011. 00000000
Netmask:   255.255.255.0 = 24   11111111.11111111.11111111. 00000000
Wildcard:  0.0.0.255            00000000.00000000.00000000. 11111111
=>
Network:   192.168.115.0/24     11000000.10101000.01110011. 00000000
HostMin:   192.168.115.1        11000000.10101000.01110011. 00000001
HostMax:   192.168.115.254      11000000.10101000.01110011. 11111110
Broadcast: 192.168.115.255      11000000.10101000.01110011. 11111111
Hosts/Net: 254                   Class C, Private Internet
```

You can use `HostMin` and `HostMax` for your Lower and Upper Address Bound respectively.

Hope that helps.

Comment: yes i did not change anything. this was **generated by default**. I also tried deleting and recreating a new one. but it always generated with `0`

Comment: uninstalling the virtualbox and reinstalling the new version 5.2, did the trick for me. thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if related but I was getting the same E_INVALIDARG error message at importing another image. I'm guessing a naming conflict was happening because once I renamed the old image the import was successful.